# Asynchronous steps execution with Cucumber (and/or Citrus)

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, citrus-framework

Suppose I have a test like below (using cucumber) -

```
Scenario: Login successfully to Facebook
  Given the user test exists
  And user name and password is entered
  When the login form is submitted
  Then I expose a HTTP-Rest service to validate the user name and password
  When I receive a validation success message
  Then display the welcome message to the user
```

Here, when `"the login form is submitted"` is called, it submit the request to a HTTP REST service which will pass the user name and password to another HTTP Rest Service (that would be exposed by Citrus Framework) using `"I expose a HTTP-Rest service to validate the user name and password"` which will validate the data and send a success response. Therefore step definitions for `"the login form is submitted"` and `"I expose a HTTP-Rest service to validate the user name and password`" should be executed asynchronously.

Could you please help me - how I could achieve this using cucumber (or/and citrus).

Note: I'm not using any `stub` application to expose the HTTP Rest service for `"I expose a HTTP-Rest service to validate the user name and password`"; I'm trying to expose the service using `Citrus` framework.

Step definitions are written in java.

Comment: What if you call `Thread.sleep` after step `the login form is submitted`?

Comment: Hello, until the execution of "When the login form is submitted" is finished, cucumber will not execute "I expose a HTTP-Rest service to validate the user name and password".

I'm looking for something by which I'll be able to execute those steps simultaneously at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to setup the citrus-cucumber extension in your project. Then you should be able to use @CitrusResource annotation that injects a test runner instance to your steps class:

```
@CitrusResource
private TestRunner runner;
```

Also you can inject the http server instance that should receive the request.

```
@CitrusEndpoint(name = "userServer")
private HttpServer userServer;
```

Then you can use test runner and the server to receive the request and send the response in a step definition:

```
@Then("^I expose a HTTP-Rest service to validate the user name and password$")
public void exposeHttpRestService() {
    runner.http(http -> http.server(userServer)
        .receive()
        .post()
        .payload("{\"username\": \"test\", \"password\": \"secret\"}"));

    runner.http(http -> http.server(userServer)
        .send()
        .response(HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

The login form should be submitted in a separate step definition using a separate thread in order to create asynchronous nature:

```
@When("^the login form is submitted$")
public void submitForm() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        // do submit the form
    });    
}
```